# How to create Dev, Test, Prod

Tags: git, github, devops

As part of my personal project, I am trying create GitHub repository with Dev, Test, and Production Branches(environments). I know that how to create Branches in GitHub, I don't know the flow of creation whether to create initially a Dev or Test or Production.

Can anyone help me out with the possible solution that How do GitHub Administrators create the Repository with all this stuff.

Comment: Pick one branch to be your “main” branch. Create your other branches from that.

Comment: There are many different workflows that you can use with git. The order you create the branches doesn't matter; what matters is the order you commit or merge changes to them, so that you know what features are ready on what branch.

Answer (score 1):

I always create a branch with this command.
If you hit them in order, there will be no problem.

```
git checkout -b dev
git checkout -b test
git checkout -b prod
```

`git checkout -b` creates a branch and navigates to that branch.

Comment: In case it's not clear, if you run these commands all in sequence, it won't make any difference which order you create them in, other than the branch you end up on - all three branches will point to the same commit. So you could equally run `git branch prod; git branch test; git branch dev; git checkout prod`